# Spring Boot. Method is not being called @RequestMapping(value= "/")

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot, request-mapping

I'm having a problem with my method that maps the localhost:8080/

I created two methods, both call the same jsp page:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index")
public ModelAndView index(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
    modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
    System.out.println("entrou no /index");
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value= "/")
public ModelAndView home(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
    modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
    System.out.println("entrou no /");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

What it calls "/index", the sysout appears in the console and the page opens.

What it calls"/", sysout does not appear on console and appears in browser " "No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/"

What am I doing wrong?
What other settings can influence this?

Comment: I created a new project and copied piece by piece of what I had done and is now working. It must have been some build problem or something with IDE